# Intraclass correlation - CI 95% in negative values?

Tags: confidence-interval, intraclass-correlation

I have my data + data from colleagues who measured independently. I have to create an ICC between my results and theirs. But the only problem is that even if I got some ICC results plus 95% CI, I don't quite know how to interpret it correctly.  I was comparing the mean values from the measurements for each batch separately. From 0.min to 60 min I got 13 values which I compared with other values.  I don't know if it is completely ok for the 95% CI to come out in the negative.

Comment: Some aspects of your problem are not clear in your question. 1) It is not clear what 0 to 60 min is in the context of your problem 2) what are those 13 values you mention? what other values did you compare them to? Is that part of how you did the ICC analysis? 3) How did you get the ICC confidence interval?. More clarity in your question will help you get useful answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I measured relative change of artificial cloth area (%) in time lapse of 60 minutes. Every 5 min I got a picture of fibrin cloth and measured its area in pixels. (there I got 13 values) - the same thing did my colleagues. So I compared my values I measured with those my colleagues measured. The CI I got from a SPSS program, using two-way mixed model and absolute type. 
Then using same model and type, I used data of lysis rate (%/min) for calculating ICC, and there I got CI 95% in greater negative values then before.

Answer (score 2):

Negative ICCs are possible. It just denoted that your within group variance is greater than your between group variance (e.g., people are more variable across timepoints than they are consistent across timepoints; judges are more different in their ratings than they are similar). The fact that your confidence interval includes these negative values means that repeated sampling should uncover an ICC between your negative value (lower bound) and upper bound 95% of the time. The fact that it contains 0 means it’s probably not particularly distinguishable from 0.